# Vb.Net Converting Greek Strings Into English

Tags: vb.net

Im building an information gathering program and some Computers like my cousin's are in greek so the name is greek. I run this

```
 Dim Name As String = Environment.UserName.ToString
```

And i get "Μητσος" Which is greek letters. Any idea of what i need to convert this string? I built by myself this function but it seems not to work.

```
Public Function ConvertToEnglish(ByVal Namee As String)
    Dim GreekName As String = Namee.ToString
    If GreekName.Contains("α") Or GreekName.Contains("Α") Then
        GreekName.Replace("α", "A")
        GreekName.Replace("Α", "A")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("β") Or GreekName.Contains("Β") Then
        GreekName.Replace("β", "B")
        GreekName.Replace("Β", "B")
    End If

    If GreekName.Contains("γ") Or GreekName.Contains("Γ") Then
        GreekName.Replace("γ", "G")
        GreekName.Replace("Γ", "G")
    End If

    If GreekName.Contains("δ") Or GreekName.Contains("Δ") Then
        GreekName.Replace("δ", "D")
        GreekName.Replace("Δ", "D")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("ε") Or GreekName.Contains("Ε") Then
        GreekName.Replace("ε", "E")
        GreekName.Replace("Ε", "E")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("ζ") Or GreekName.Contains("Ζ") Then
        GreekName.Replace("ζ", "Z")
        GreekName.Replace("Ζ", "Z")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("η") Or GreekName.Contains("Η") Then
        GreekName.Replace("η", "I")
        GreekName.Replace("Η", "I")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("θ") Or GreekName.Contains("Θ") Then
        GreekName.Replace("θ", "TH")
        GreekName.Replace("Θ", "TH")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("ι") Or GreekName.Contains("Ι") Then
        GreekName.Replace("ι", "I")
        GreekName.Replace("Ι", "I")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("κ") Or GreekName.Contains("Κ") Then
        GreekName.Replace("κ", "K")
        GreekName.Replace("Κ", "K")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("λ") Or GreekName.Contains("Λ") Then
        GreekName.Replace("λ", "L")
        GreekName.Replace("Λ", "L")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("μ") Or GreekName.Contains("Μ") Then
        GreekName.Replace("μ", "M")
        GreekName.Replace("Μ", "M")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("ν") Or GreekName.Contains("Ν") Then
        GreekName.Replace("ν", "N")
        GreekName.Replace("Ν", "N")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("ξ") Or GreekName.Contains("Ξ") Then
        GreekName.Replace("ξ", "KS")
        GreekName.Replace("Ξ", "KS")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("ο") Or GreekName.Contains("Ο") Then
        GreekName.Replace("ο", "o")
        GreekName.Replace("Ο", "o")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("π") Or GreekName.Contains("Π") Then
        GreekName.Replace("π", "P")
        GreekName.Replace("Π", "P")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("ρ") Or GreekName.Contains("Ρ") Then
        GreekName.Replace("ρ", "R")
        GreekName.Replace("Ρ", "R")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("σ") Or GreekName.Contains("Σ") Then
        GreekName.Replace("σ", "S")
        GreekName.Replace("Σ", "S")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("τ") Or GreekName.Contains("Τ") Then
        GreekName.Replace("τ", "T")
        GreekName.Replace("Τ", "T")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("υ") Or GreekName.Contains("Υ") Then
        GreekName.Replace("υ", "Y")
        GreekName.Replace("Υ", "Y")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("φ") Or GreekName.Contains("Φ") Then
        GreekName.Replace("φ", "F")
        GreekName.Replace("Φ", "F")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("χ") Or GreekName.Contains("Χ") Then
        GreekName.Replace("χ", "X")
        GreekName.Replace("Χ", "X")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("ψ") Or GreekName.Contains("Ψ") Then
        GreekName.Replace("ψ", "PS")
        GreekName.Replace("Ψ", "PS")
    End If
    If GreekName.Contains("ω") Or GreekName.Contains("Ω") Then
        GreekName.Replace("ω", "W")
        GreekName.Replace("Ω", "W")
    End If


    Return GreekName.ToString
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace is not an "in-place" replacement, but returns a value. You have to assign the return value to the variable.

```
GreekName = GreekName.Replace("ω", "W")
```

Note that you don't have to test the existence of the replaced character beforehand. If the character is not found, it just does nothing.

Comment: If it solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (the checkmark next to the answer)

Comment: @FrozenBlade - "Strings are immutable" - that's is why you cannot replace a value in the string.

Comment: @MattWilko I Understood my mistake. Now the programm works and i continue developing. Thanks once again